# Weird positioning of image view. Wrong content mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want my image view to be displayed correctly at the bottom of the main view, but apparently the image is tilted to the top. I have tried to use every possible content mode of the image view, but none of them place the image view in the right position (bottom).

There's something wrong going on with the image, even though I set my layout constraints right. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Image here]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))

let groundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"GroundSkin.png"))
mainView.addSubview(groundView)
groundView.backgroundColor = .red
groundView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
groundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
groundView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
groundView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
groundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
groundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Hm, I see you are adding groundView to your mainView before actually setting all the properties & constraints. Try calling `addSubview()` after all those commands? Also does your mainView have constraints on it? Maybe mainView's anchors need to be defined too? Sorry would try this out but no Xcode access now

Comment: Thanks @DanielLegler. I can't call addSubview to the main view after setting up the constraints - that causes a crash because you can't set up a constraint if you don't add it to the view in the first place. mainView does have no constraint, just a frame (I am inside a playground).

Comment: Do you know the size of the image at compile time? @JimboPower

Comment: Also, just as a note, you have _not_ set your constraint correctly. More on that in a moment if you can get back to me on the above.

Comment: @MichaelFourre The size of the image at compile time is 792.0, 357.0 (the main view size is (1000, 1000), so is the size of the image view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending part of this is the `heightAnchor` constraint of `groundView`, which you are setting equal to the equivalent constraint of `mainView`. Doing this will only result in the `groundView` gripping the top and bottom anchors of the `mainView` and centering the image vertically in an undesirable way.

One thing that I'm a bit confused about is your expectation with the red background. If you really want your image to fit in a certain area, then it's best to constrain your `UIImageView` how you want it and then set your content mode based on your requirements. Do this instead of constraining `UIImageView` to whatever and trying to get the content mode to do things that it isn't meant to do. If this is done, the red background should (optimally) not even show at all; it would be the background color of the `mainView` that would show underneath it all.

If you want the `groundView` image to display at the bottom of the `mainView` while filling the view horizontally, the best approach would be to replace the `groundView.heightAnchor` constraint with an aspect ratio based on its own size (which you noted is specified at compile time). So if your image was 4x3 in dimension, for example, this constraint:

```
groundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```

would turn into:

```
groundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: groundView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 3.0/4.0).isActive = true
```

Using this, the image should still grow and shrink based on device orientation and screen size, but will only do so as long as its aspect ratio matches that which you expect (in this example, 4x3).

In my Playground, I got a test image from the internet and threw it into `groundView` while setting `mainView`'s `backgroundColor` attribute to `.yellow` for demonstration. The result was:

[image: example of hugging bottom of main view]

My test photo was not quite the same ratio as yours, but you get the point. The end result is that the image hugs the bottom of the container, resizes to fit the width of the container, and maintains its own aspect ratio.

If you wish to implement this yourself, note of course that your aspect ratio is probably different, so you would have to change `3.0/4.0` to something else until it looks how you would like it to look.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Michael, thank you so much for your excellent answer! I appreciate you taking the time to thoroughly answer my question and helping me solve the problem.

Comment: I'm happy to help out